# Extraer palabra de un archivo txt

Tags: php

acabo de empezar en el mundo de php hacer poco y no consigo extraer unas palabras de un texto. Se trata de un texto fijo por lo que los datos que quiero conseguir están siempre en la misma posición. He conseguido extraerlas sabiendo cuales son las palabras a extraer pero no si son aleatorias.
Os dejo un ejemplo de lo que pretendo conseguir. El código muestra como parto el texto en lineas (la idea es coger la palabras en rojo de la 4 linea)
Saludos!
[image: En rojo las "palabras" que pretendo conseguir]

```
    <?php
    $file = fopen("ejemplo.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    while(!feof($file))
     {
     echo fgets($file). "<br />";
     }
    fclose($file);
   ?>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código en vez de la imagen, es más fácil reproducir el ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: No tengo mucho código que mostrar puesto que no se como atacar el asunto. He añadido el código que utilizo para obtener cada linea del texto por separado

Comment: podes usar [`$lineas = file( ...);`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) así te lo carga en un array que podes ir recorriendo y a cada línea luego le hacés un [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) para separar las columnas en otro array